# How to aggregate distance in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, postgis

I have the following query

```
query = Studio.query.join(
        Location
    ).filter(
        func.ST_DWithin(Location.point, point, distance)
    ).order_by(
        func.ST_Distance(Location.point, point).label('distance')
    )
```

how to aggregate distance to attribute ? e.g:

```
query[0].distance
```

or

```
query[0].location.distance
```

Comment: Add the `distance` to the queried columns/entities: `session.query(Studio, func.ST_Distance(Location.point, point).label('distance')).join(Location). ...`. Then the results will be not a collection of `Studio`s, but of tuples `(Studio, distance)`.

Comment: but how to add to studio collection ?

Comment: After you get results, you can do: `for studio, distance in query: studio.distance = distance`.

Comment: I want to use sqlachemy-marshmallow to serialize to json. I don't want iterate two times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I'm using generator to inject property

```
def smart_generator(query, column_name):
    for obj, additional_data in query.all():
        setattr(obj, column_name, additional_data)
        yield obj


distance_query = StudioLocation.point.ST_Distance(point).label('distance')
nearby_query = Location.point.ST_DWithin(point, distance)
studio_query = db.session.query(Studio, distance_query).join(Location)
studio_query = studio_query.filter(nearby_query).order_by('distance')
studio = smart_generator(studio_query, "distance")
```